# Why the indentation in the while loop create problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, indentation

I want to create a list of 1 to 14 without 5 & 10 with while loop in Python, while it appeared a indentation problem. Why the indentation create the while loop problem?

the below was my code before and after

The code before:

```
total = 0
number = 1
while number <= 15:
    if number%5 == 0:
        number += 1
        continue
    print("%3d"%(number), end = "")
total += number
number += 1
print("\ntotal = %d"%(total))
```

the code after

```
total = 0
number = 1
while number <= 15:
    if number%5 == 0:
        number += 1
        continue
    print("%3d"%(number), end = "")
    total += number
    number += 1
print("\ntotal = %d"%(total))
```

I expect the result be 
1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14
total = 90

Comment: In the first code `total += number` and `number +=1` weren't being executed until after the while loop had completed while in the second code block they are being executed with each loop of the while loop

Comment: ...how is python supposed to know what code is part of the loop's body if you don't indent it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python depends on indentation to know what block of statements to run in a loop.

In other words, **Same indentation = Same block**

I'd say add comments for blocks till you're comfortable with them!

```
while number <= 15:
    # LOOP BLOCK STARTS HERE

    if number%5 == 0:
        # IF BLOCK STARTS HERE

        number += 1
        continue

        # IF BLOCK ENDS HERE

    print("%3d"%(number), end = "")
    total += number
    number += 1

    # LOOP BLOCK ENDS HERE

print("\ntotal = %d"%(total))
```

If you don't indent statements to same block, Python will treat them as different blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Indentions in Python is not just for readability, it also creates a new block of code, look [Here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) for more information.
in the first posted code the lines:

```
total += number
number += 1
```

are out of the `while` block. so it will not be executed in each iteration of the loop but it will execute after the loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way might be easier to you to understand

```
total = 0
number = 0
while number <= 15:
    #If number is not divisible by 5, add it to total
    if number%5 != 0:
        total+=number
    #Always increment the number
    number += 1
    print("%3d"%(number), end = "")
print("\ntotal = %d"%(total))
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
#total = 90
```